# javax.swing.JDialog is appearing twice on windows device

Tags: swing

I have created a JDialog to be opened when I click on the edit button of my JFrame, it is being opened properly and does'nt have any issue, but when I took this code on the windows ce 5.0 device this dialog is being opened twice. hat is i am clicking only once on the edit button but the dialog is appearing twice, I want there should be only one dialog appear on  edit button click.

Comment: Sounds like you have a second call somewhere. Can you tell us more about the differences of the tested environments and maybe show some code?

Comment: there is no other call to the dialog, the issue is on the device only on my desktop it is working as expected but when i put the jar of this code on the win ce device, there it is shown twice.

Comment: I am using ListSelectionListener, when i click on any item of the list the valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) method is invoked in that method i have displayed that jdialog, but on the device this method is getting called twice.

Comment: public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {List lsm = (List) e.getSource(); showDialog();lsm.clearSelection();  }

Comment: ok I have got the solution public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {if (e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false) {List lsm = (List) e.getSource(); showDialog();lsm.clearSelection(); } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I have got the solution

```
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    if (e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false) {
        List lsm = (List) e.getSource();
        showDialog();
        lsm.clearSelection();
    }
}
```

Comment: The predicate `!e.getValueIsAdjusting()` is a common alternative to `e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false`.